# Why is there no std::is_transparent equivalent for unordered containers?

Tags: c++, c++14

C++14 introduces `Compare::is_transparent` for equivalent [find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find) operations in associative containers.

```
template< class K > iterator       find( const K& x );
template< class K > const_iterator find( const K& x ) const;
```

> Finds an element with key that compares equivalent to the value x.
>   This overload only participates in overload resolution if the
>   qualified-id Compare::is_transparent is valid and denotes a type. It
>   allows calling this function without constructing an instance of Key

Since there is no longer temporary instance of `Key` constructed, these can be more efficient.

There does not seem to be an **equivalent for unordered containers**.

Why is there no `Compare::key_equal` / `Compare::hash_equal`?

I imagine it would be relatively simple to allow efficiently looking up of, eg, string literals in unordered containers?

```
template<>
struct hash<string>
{
    std::size_t operator()(const string& s) const 
    {
        return ...;
    }
    // hash_equal=true allows hashing string literals
    std::size_t operator()(const char* s) const
    {
        return ...;
    }
};
```

Comment: [N3573: Heterogenous extensions to unordered containers](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3573.html)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Keys that compare equal should produce the same hash value. Decoupling the hash function and the predicate, *and* at the same time making one or both heterogeneous, could be too much error prone.

Recent paper, [P0919r2](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0919r2.html), brings up the following example:

```
std::hash<long>{}(-1L) == 18446744073709551615ULL
std::hash<double>{}(-1.0) == 11078049357879903929ULL
```

Although `-1L` and `-1.0` compare equal, some heterogeneous hash function, not in line with the selected equality comparison logic, could produce different values. The paper adds heterogeneous lookup-enabled function templates --
`find`, `count`, `equal_­range`, and `contains` -- but makes them available when the below requirements are met [[unord.req]/p17](http://eel.is/c++draft/unord.req#17):

> If the *qualified-id* `Hash::transparent_­key_­equal` is valid and denotes a type ([temp.deduct]), then the program is ill-formed if either:
>
> - *qualified-id* `Hash::transparent_­key_­equal::is_­transparent` is not valid or does not denote a type, or
> - `Pred` is a different type than `equal_­to<Key>` or `Hash::transparent_­key_­equal`.
>
> The member function templates `find`, `count`, `equal_­range`, and `contains` shall not participate in overload resolution unless the *qualified-id* `Hash::transparent_­key_equal` is valid and denotes a type ([temp.deduct]).

In such a case, `Hash::transparent_­key_­equal` overwrites the default predicate (`std::equal_to<Key>`) and is used for (transparent) equality checking, together with `Hash` itself for (transparent) hashing.

Under these conditions, the below transparent function objects could be used to enable heterogeneous lookup:

```
struct string_equal
{
    using is_transparent = void;

    bool operator()(const std::string& l, const std::string& r) const
    {
        return l.compare(r) == 0; 
    }

    bool operator()(const std::string& l, const char* r) const 
    {
        return l.compare(r) == 0; 
    }

    bool operator()(const char* l, const std::string& r) const
    {
        return r.compare(l) == 0; 
    }
};

struct string_hash
{
    using transparent_key_equal = string_equal; // or std::equal_to<>

    std::size_t operator()(const std::string& s) const
    {
        return s.size();
    }

    std::size_t operator()(const char* s) const
    {
        return std::strlen(s);
    }
};
```

Both -- `string_equal` and `std::equal_to<>` -- are transparent comparators and can be used as `transparent_key_equal` for `string_hash`.

Having this type alias (or a type definition itself) within the hash function class definition **makes it clear** that it is a valid predicate that works fine with that particular hashing logic and the two can't diverge. Such an unordered set can be declared as:

```
std::unordered_set<std::string, string_hash> u;
```

or:

```
std::unordered_set<std::string, string_hash, string_hash::transparent_key_equal> u;
```

Either will use `string_hash` and `string_equal`.

Comment: You know, the example can be simplified with `std::string_view` in C++17.

Comment: @Deduplicator yes, the implementation is for demonstration purposes

Comment: [P0919r3](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0919r3.html) was voted into C++20 in San Diego. (see [Herbs Trip Report](https://herbsutter.com/2018/11/13/trip-report-fall-iso-c-standards-meeting-san-diego/))

Comment: Attention! The provided solution has not found it's way to the mainstream compilers yet!  I've just spent one and half hours trying to understand why my heterogeneous lookup does not work (https://pastebin.com/ic2NZpmw).  Then it struck me to check if this feature has been already implemented.  The P0919R3 has not been implemented neither in GCC https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html, nor in clang https://libcxx.llvm.org/cxx2a_status.html.  It seems the reason the described solution works is that there's an implicit conversion between `char *` and `string` so the example compiles.

Comment: Also, looks like `transparent_key_equal` has been left in favor of `is_transparent` in the `Hash` type, compare the current documentation (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/UnorderedAssociativeContainer) with a previous version (https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:bvL_G4Y71YoJ:https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/UnorderedAssociativeContainer+&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=de).  @PiotrSkotnicki Do you mind editing your answer to mention that this feature is not yet implemented and that `transparent_key_equal` might be substituted by `is_transparent`?

Answer (score 6):

If you watch the [Grill the committee](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PqU_ot4BlNQ) video from CppCon, they explain why stuff like this happens: nobody fought for it.

C++ is standardized by committee but that committee requires input from the community.  Someone has to write papers, respond to criticism, go to the meetings, etc...  Then the feature can be voted on.  The committee doesn't just sit there inventing language and library features.  It only discusses and votes on those that are brought forward to it.

Comment: I don't know which proposal brought `is_transparent`, but I would have thought it a relatively small enhancement to the proposal to include the unordered containers. I wonder why this question wasn't brought up in the review process?

Comment: So would you say that there is no technical reason why this couldn't be implemented, rather that no-one fought for it?

Answer (score 0):

The following example (derived from the accepted answer) compiles on Apple clang version 13.1.6. Note that I had to put `is_transparent` both in `NodeHash` and `NodeEq`.

```cpp
#include <unordered_set>

struct Node {
    int id;
    int count;
};

struct NodeEq {
    using is_transparent = void;
    bool operator() (Node const& a, Node const& b) const { return a.id == b.id; };
    bool operator() (Node const& n, int const i)   const { return n.id == i; };
    bool operator() (int const i,   Node const& n) const { return n.id == i; };
};

struct NodeHash {
    using is_transparent = void;
    using transparent_key_equal = NodeEq;
    std::size_t operator() (Node const& n) const noexcept { return n.id; };
    std::size_t operator() (int n)         const noexcept { return n;    };
};

using nodes_t = std::unordered_set< Node, NodeHash, NodeHash::transparent_key_equal >;

int main() {
    nodes_t nodes;
    nodes.find(1);
}
```

Comment: My question was asked in 2015. Heterogeneous lookup for unordered containers was added in C++20

Comment: I know - you are so much ahead of me! However, an up-to-date example might be useful to someone (or so I hoped). I struggled a bit before I got it right.

Comment: Note that in the end, `transparent_key_equal` didn't [make it through](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1690r1.html).